# No Postgis after installing opengeo suite

Tags: boundless-suite

After the installation of the opengeo suite; everything seems to work fine, except for the postgis extension of postgresql. In the dashboard all the postgis options are greyed out.

The system is running Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise) LTS Bare OS.

Is there a way to install postgis afterwards with the templates from opengeo?

Comment: http://workshops.opengeo.org/postgis-spatialdbtips/installation.html is the old manual way with a few linux tips

Comment: I don't know why all the documentation on the web excludes the -h parameter but loading psql won't work without it for me? I instantly get the peer authentication error. For example,
psql -d medford -h localhost -p 5432 -U opengeo -c "SELECT postgis_full_version();"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually on Linux installations the postgis specific functionality on the dashboard is explicitly disabled since it's not running as a native app. So unless you saw some installation errors it is probably fine. You can verify by logging into the database from the terminal. Try this.

psql -U opengeo medford
  select postgis_version();

If that all works everything should be fine.

Comment: That is not working: `psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "opengeo"`. I don't know if the installation produced errors, it started it and went off.

Comment: Actually I had to do some authentication first; and then I opened up remote configuration.... stil not working completely but I'm getting there! Thank you.

Comment: @jdeolive: your terminal command generated an error: bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('. I tried this command: psql -U opengeo medford -c"select postgis_version();" and it runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same situation as yours (installed Opengeo suite on a clean Ubuntu 12.04 OS - found greyed out items for PostGIS in Opengeo Dashboard) - with some errors in the opengeo suite installation process:

```
Error in `/usr/share/doc-base/pgadmin3-enus', line 8: all `Format' sections are invalid.
Note: `install-docs --verbose --check file_name' may give more details about the above error.
```

And

```
psql: FATAL:  database "template_postgis" does not exist
psql: FATAL:  database "medford" does not exist
psql:/usr/share/opengeo-postgis/medford_taxlots_schema.sql:9: ERROR:  schema "opengeo" already exists
psql:/usr/share/opengeo-postgis/medford_taxlots_schema.sql:13: ERROR:  index "medford_taxlots_gix" does not exist
psql:/usr/share/opengeo-postgis/medford_taxlots_schema.sql:14: ERROR:  relation "public.medford_taxlots" does not exist
psql:/usr/share/opengeo-postgis/medford_taxlots_schema.sql:15: ERROR:  table "medford_taxlots" does not exist
psql: FATAL:  database "geoserver" does not exist
```

But when I opened pgAdmin3 and log in, PostGIS and some pre-installed database were there.