# Problem with PostGIS in Opengeo Suite in Ubuntu 13?

Tags: postgis, boundless-suite

Everything is working fine after installing the Opengeo Suite in Ubuntu except PostGIS issues. In the dashboard the PostGIS manage is disabled(grey) but PostgreSQL is working via pgadmin3. And also when we create a new database the tables "Geometry Columns" & "Spatial Ref_System" isn't getting created. Also we are not able to import any shape files.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to spatially enable new databases yourself, they won't be spatially enabled by default. Try running 'create extension postgis' inside one of your new databases and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

"On Linux installations the postgis specific functionality on the dashboard is explicitly disabled since it's not running as a native app." (see [No Postgis after installing opengeo suite](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48737/no-postgis-after-installing-opengeo-suite)).

To get the tables "Geometry Columns" & "Spatial Ref_System", you need to spatially enable the database (see [here](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.4/ch02.html#id2754935) for the command line commands or [here](http://workshops.opengeo.org/postgis-intro/creating_db.html#creating-a-database) using pgAdmin3).

To import shape files have a look at [the documentation](http://suite.opengeo.org/docs/dataadmin/pgGettingStarted/pgshapeloader.html) or explain your problem in more detail.

Moreover, note that the OpenGeo is officially supported only for Ubuntu 10.04, however it is reported to work well also under 12.10. I had troubles with 13.04 myself, see [GeoServer Web Admin Interface: 404 error](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61629/geoserver-web-admin-interface-404-error).